# How to rename root key in JSON serialization with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, root

I am using Jackson for JSON serialization of a list of objects.

Here is what I get:

```
{"ArrayList":[{"id":1,"name":"test name"}]}
```

But I want this :

```
{"rootname":[{"id":1,"name":"test name"}]} // ie showing the string I want as the root name.
```

Below is my approach to this:

Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public long getId();
    public String getName();
}
```

Implementation class:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "rootname")
public class MyImpl implements MyInterface {
    private final long id;
    private String name;

    public MyImpl(final long id,final name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

   // getters     
}
```

JSon serialization:

```
public class MySerializer {
    public static String serializeList(final List<MyInterface> lists) {
        //check for null value.Throw Exception
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(lists);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
final List<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<MyImpl>();
MyImpl item = new MyImpl(1L,"test name");
list.add(item);
final String json = MySerializer.serializeList(list);
System.out.println(json);
```

Here is what I get:

```
{"ArrayList":[{"id":1,"name":"test name"}]}
```

But I want this :

```
{"rootname":[{"id":1,"name":"test name"}]} // ie showing the string I want as the root     name.
```

I have tried all suggested solutions I could find but failed to achieve my goal. I have looked at:

- [Jackson : custom collection serialization to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954265/jackson-custom-collection-serialization-to-json)
- [How do I rename the root key of a JSON with Java Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034933/how-do-i-rename-the-root-key-of-a-json-with-java-jackson)
- [Jackson : custom collection serialization to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954265/jackson-custom-collection-serialization-to-json)

Or am I missing something? I am using jackson 1.9.12 for this. Any help in this regard is welcome.

Comment: try serializing an instance of MyImpl not a List of MyImpl. The serializer is doing his job since he is wrapping a List and not a MyInterface object.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Well, by default Jackson uses one of two annotations when trying to determine the root name to be displayed for wrapped values - [`@XmlRootElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html) or [`@JsonRootName`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonRootName.html). It expects this annotation to be on the type being serialized, else it will use the [simple name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29) of the type as the root name.

In your case, you are serializing a list, which is why the root name is 'ArrayList' (simple name of the type being serialized). Each element in the list may be of a type annotated with @JsonRootName, but the list itself ***is not***.

When the root value you are trying to wrap is a collection then you need some way of defining the wrap name:

#### Holder/Wrapper Class

You can create a wrapper class to hold the list, with an annotation to define the desired property name (*you only need to use this method when you do not have direct control of the `ObjectMapper`/JSON transformation process*):

```
class MyInterfaceList {
    @JsonProperty("rootname")
    private List<MyInterface> list;

    public List<MyInterface> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<MyInterface> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}

final List<MyInterface> lists = new ArrayList<MyInterface>(4);
lists.add(new MyImpl(1L, "test name"));
MyInterfaceList listHolder = new MyInterfaceList();
listHolder.setList(lists);
final String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(listHolder);
```

#### Object Writer

This is the preferable option. Use a configured [`ObjectWriter`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html) instance to generate the JSON. In particular, we are interested in the [`withRootName`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html#withRootName%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
final List<MyInterface> lists = new ArrayList<MyInterface>(4);
lists.add(new MyImpl(1L, "test name"));
final ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer().withRootName("rootName");
final String json = writer.writeValueAsString(lists);
```

Comment: For the case when you create an objectmapper and pass it to 3rd party libs, how can you implement the ObjectWriter case generically? I see no way to tell jackson "Use this objectwriter for these types all the time".

Comment: Do it all in one line `new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE).writer().withRootName("rootName").writeValueAsString(lists)`

Answer (score 20):

I know, I am late , but I have better approach which don't require Holder/Wrapper Class. It picks root key from annotation.

```
package com.test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;


@JsonRootName("Products")
public class ProductDTO {
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Here is test class:-

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class ProductDTOTestCase {
    @Test
    public void testPersistAndFindById() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ProductDTO productDTO = new ProductDTO();
        productDTO.setDescription("Product 4 - Test");

        ArrayList<ProductDTO> arrayList = new ArrayList<ProductDTO>();
        arrayList.add(productDTO);

        String rootName = ProductDTO.class.getAnnotation(JsonRootName.class).value();
        System.out.println(mapper.writer().withRootName(rootName).writeValueAsString(arrayList));

    }


}
```

It will give following output

```
{"Products":[{"name":null,"description":"Product 4 - Test"}]}
```

Comment: This also works with the Jackson `XmlMapper` to generate XML instead of JSON.

Answer (score 11):

```
@JsonTypeName("usuarios")
@JsonTypeInfo(include= JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT,use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
public class UsuarioDT extends ArrayList<Usuario> {

    @JsonProperty("rowsAffected")
    private Integer afectados;

    public Integer getAfectados() {
        return afectados;
    }

    public void setAfectados(Integer afectados) {
        this.afectados = afectados;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation as to ***why*** this is the answer.

Comment: Really great answer ++

Comment: used this and now I have to change 10 microservice endpoints hehe, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this annotation at the top of the class

`@JsonTypeName("rootname")`

Comment: if you are referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/43638999/8857427 then indeed is not required but the output will be the classname with first letter as Capital. (i.e UsuarioDT). To eliminate this, then you could use @JsonTypeName("usuarioDT").