# spring-boot json root name

Tags: json, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot 1.3.3 and trying to figure out how to have root names on JSON serialization. For example, I would like...

```
{ stores: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Store1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Store2"
  }]
}
```

but instead I am getting

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Store1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Store2"
  }
]
```

I've been looking at `@JsonRootName` and customizing the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` config but to no avail. In grails, this is pretty simple with Json Views and I was trying also to see how that translated directly to spring-boot but still can't seem to figure it out.

I realize this is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022795/how-to-wrap-a-list-as-top-level-element-in-json-generated-by-jackson) question but I feel like in the context of Spring (boot) it might be applied differently and would like to know how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wrap a List as top level element in JSON generated by Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022795/how-to-wrap-a-list-as-top-level-element-in-json-generated-by-jackson)

Comment: Possibly, but in the context of Spring (boot) oft times it is different / easier / etc. So still would like to know if there is actually a "spring" way of doing this.

Comment: Not to my knowledge an easy way other than wrapping

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Solution 1: Jackson JsonRootName**

> I've been looking at `@JsonRootName` and
>
> customizing the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` config but to no avail

What are your errors with `@JsonRootName` and the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`?

This works in my Spring Boot (1.3.3) implementation:

**Jackson configuration Bean**

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.featuresToEnable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE); 
        // enables wrapping for root elements
        return builder;
    }
}
```

Reference: [Spring Documentation - Customizing the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#with-spring-boot)

**Add @JsonRootElement to your response entity**

```
@JsonRootName(value = "lot")
public class LotDTO { ... }
```

**Json Result** for HTTP-GET */lot/1*

```
{
  "lot": {
    "id": 1,
    "attributes": "...",
    }
}
```

At least this works for a response with one object.

I haven't figured out how to customize the root name in a collection. @Perceptions' answer might help [How to rename root key in JSON serialization with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936680/how-to-rename-root-key-in-json-serialization-with-jackson)

---

### EDIT

**Solution 2: Without Jackson configuration**

> Since I couldn't figure out how to customize the json root name in a collection with Kackson
>
> I adapted the answer from @Vaibhav (see [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936680/how-to-rename-root-key-in-json-serialization-with-jackson)):

**Custom Java Annotation**

```
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomJsonRootName {
    String singular(); // element root name for a single object
    String plural(); // element root name for collections
}
```

**Add annotation to DTO**

```
@CustomJsonRootName(plural = "articles", singular = "article")
public class ArticleDTO { // Attributes, Getter and Setter }
```

**Return a Map as result in Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<ArticleDTO>>> findAll() {
  List<ArticleDTO> articles = articleService.findAll();
  if (articles.isEmpty()) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
  }
  Map result = new HashMap();
  result.put(ArticleDTO.class.getAnnotation(CustomJsonRootName.class).plural(), articles);
  return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

SpringBoot use Jackson as json tool, so this will work well:

```
@JsonTypeName("stores")
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
public class stores { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is the best so far, it's way shorter and is very flexible, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found a really easy way to do that. Instead of returning an

```
ArrayList<Object>
```

of your objects to the frontend, just return a

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>
```

and initilize the list of your objects and the according HashMap in the following way:

```
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
```

... fill your objectList with your objects and then:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>> returnMap = new HashMap<>();
returnMap.put("lot", objectList);
return returnMap;
```

The head of your controller method looks someting like this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/link", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public HashMap<String, List<Object>> processQuestions(@RequestBody List<incomingObject> controllerMethod) {
```

This will result in the desired JSON without further definitions through annotations or whatever.

Comment: I actually had moved to this exact model with the only exception being that I created an annotation to hold the pluralized version of the root name so I can pull it off as the key in the map instead of a hardcoded string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to return `Map <String, Object>`.
Just put the key as 'stores' and object as stores object.

ex-

```
Map<String, Object> response = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();


response.put("stores", stores)
```