# Customize Jackson XML output when using @JsonView in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson2, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am using the `@JsonView` annotation to output a simplified version of a complex object in Spring MVC.

The View:

```
public class UserView {
    public interface Summary {}
}
```

The entity class:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 255)
    @JsonView(UserView.Summary.class)
    private String name;
```

The resource method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "users", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
@JsonView(UserView.Summary.class)
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAllBy();
}
```

This works perfect when outputting JSON:

```
[
    {"name": "User 1"},
    {"name": "User 2"}
]
```

But when the "Content-Type" is set to XML, the following output is returned:

```
<List>
    <item>
        <name>User 1</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>User 2</name>
    </item>
</List>
```

I'd like to have `<Users>` instead of `<List>` and `<User>` instead of `<item>`, but I couldn't find a way of changing these generic names. I've tried annotations like `@XmlRootElement(name="user")` or `@XmlElementWrapper(name="users")`, but no luck.

Comment: Could you please provide feedback to the answers ? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @SagarVeeram, yes, sorry. I've tried both answers and they both work. I'm going to accept the first one that was provided. Thank you so much for both your contributions!

Comment: @viorel In my case, the xml output is unaffected by JsonView, but json renders perfectly. How did you make yours work could you please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@XmlElementWrapper` is generally a good way to do that.
But this only works when the list is inside an entity.

I'd recommend to not return `List<User>` but instead a `Users` Entity (notice the plural) with the attribute `users`.
We can even omit the `@XmlElementWrapper` here since the Entity itself is the element wrapper.

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Users implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1337L;

    @XmlElement(name = "User")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```xml
<Users>
    <User>
        <name>User 1</name>
    </User>
    <User>
        <name>User 2</name>
    </User>
</Users>
```

Answer (score 1):

Collections at the root level support is limited for xml mapper ( see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022795/how-to-wrap-a-list-as-top-level-element-in-json-generated-by-jackson) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936680/how-to-rename-root-key-in-json-serialization-with-jackson/15937274#15937274) (answers are little dated but you should get the idea ) but collections as pojo property are fully supported. So for customization it is better to create a wrapper.

Also note @JsonView(UserView.Summary.class) to the wrapper property for spring to pick it up.

Something like

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Users")
public class CollectionWrapper {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "User")
    @JsonView(UserView.Summary.class)
    private List<User> users;

    public CollectionWrapper(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

}
```

Resource

```
@GetMapping(value = "users", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
@JsonView(UserView.Summary.class)
public CollectionWrapper getAllUsers() {
    return new CollectionWrapper(userRepository.findAllBy());
}
```

Output

```
<Users>
    <User>
        <name>User 1</name>
    </User>
    <User>
        <name>User 2</name>
    </User>
</Users>
```